# Moment js showing wrong time when i format

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to convert java datetime instant to hh:mm format using moment js

```
moment("2020-03-21T17:34:00Z").utcOffset(-0500).format("hh:mm")
```

it should give me 12:34, but somehow it is giving "12:14" which is the wrong time.

Answer (score 1):

The moment js `.utcOffset()` method takes the offset in minutes.

so if you want to get `12:34` you need to use `-300` instead of `-0500`

```
moment("2020-03-21T17:34:00Z").utcOffset(-300).format("hh:mm")
```

Comment: I will be getting "dttm": "2020-03-21T17:34:00Z",
        "dttmLocleId": "US/Central",
        "dttmUtcOffset": "-0500"

then i cant manipulate the offset

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- The `utcOffset` function behaves differently whether you pass a string or a number.  As a number, it's expected to be in terms of minutes. Since you have hours and minutes in your offset, you should pass it as a string:  `.utcOffset("-0500")`
- Format strings are case sensitive.  You should use `HH:mm` (24-hour time), or `hh:mm a` (12-hour time).  Since you used `hh:mm` without an `a`, anything after 12 pm will be misrepresented.
- You are supplying a fixed offset.  If that is your intent, then ok.  But do recognize that there is a difference between an offset and a time zone.  (See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).)  For example, if you wanted to convert to US Eastern Time, you should use `.tz('America/New_York`) instead of `.utcOffset("-0500")`. (US Eastern time is at -4 for the date given, not -5.)  You would need the moment-timezone addon to make this work.
- Lastly, recognize that Moment is in maintenance mode.  The moment team generally recommends [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) for new development.